# Change the magnifying glass icon on a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, uisearchbar

I want to be able to set my own image for the little magnifying glass icon on a UISearchBar. I'd also like to be able to move it around if possible. Any ideas? Currently, I only need support for iOS5 and above.

Comment: @ACB was kind enough to answer this in another posting I had about UISearchBar where I asked this as an added question in the comments. He said: "You can use for iOS 5 app as mentioned below. For apps which uses OS version before this, this wont work. - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state;"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For apps which supports iOS 5 onwards, you can use the below method to do this,

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state;
```

`UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateDisabled` are the two possible states for search bar.

For apps which uses OS version before this, this wont work. You might have to create a category on `UISearchbar` and change the icon by enumerating the subviews.

Comment: For others who are lazy or wanted a little further clarification (for example that this is a method for the UISearchBar):
`[self.searchController.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageHere"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];`
or wherever else you have your search controller/bar

Answer (score 13):

If you want to just change the color of the default magnifying icon, you can set the image to use template mode and then set the image view’s tintColor.

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    UITextField *textField = (id)view;

    UIImageView *iconView = (id)textField.leftView;
    iconView.image = [iconView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    iconView.tintColor = <##dimmedColor##>;

    // other styling:
    textField.font = <##font##>;
    textField.textColor = <##activeColor##>;
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:<##searchBar##>.placeholder
                                                                      attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: <##dimmedColor##>}];
}
```

Comment: The imageWithRenderingMode was key. Missed it at first glance!

Answer (score 3):

For Swift :-

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "new_search_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)iconImage forSearchBarIcon:(UISearchBarIcon)icon state:(UIControlState)state;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

```
  searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "your_favicon"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```

Answer (score -2):

try print all subviews... iOS indipendent.

```
for (id obj in _SearchBar.subviews) {
  NSLog(@"%@", obj);

  if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]] )  {
     NSLog(@"probably found...");

     UIImage *img = obj;
     [img setImage....];
  }
}
```